# How to create javax.mail.Session in spring config

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

```
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("example@gmail.com","password");
            }
        });
```

I just want to have a spring bean configuration for this session. How to create the javax.mail.Authenticator() bean in spring xml??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out a solution for that..

```
<bean id="passwordAuth" class="javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>${sender.email}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>${sender.password}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<bean id="authenticator" class="javax.mail.Authenticator">
    <lookup-method name="getPasswordAuthentication" bean="passwordAuth" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailSession" class="javax.mail.Session">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.host">${mail.smtp.host}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">${mail.smtp.port}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">${mail.smtp.socketFactory.class}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">${mail.smtp.port}</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticator" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides the org.springframework.mail package for encapsulating the Java Mail bean and simplifies the email component.

For example -

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/